# SQL to find mutual friends from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the mutual friends with SQL from a single table

I have a simple table with 2 fields user, friends as int.  Data values as are as below

[image: Table content]

**Expected Output**

user    friend  mutual friends

---

1       2       2

---

1 3 1

This is the query i tried

select ex1.user,ex2.friend, count(distinct ex3.friend) from (select distinct user from exer1) ex1
join exer1 ex2, exer1 ex3
where ex1.user=ex2.user and
ex2.user<>ex3.user and ex2.friend<>ex3.friend
group by ex1.user,ex2.friend order by 1,2

The output i got was

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEf3F.png)

The desired output I am looking for is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk4Pz.png)

Comment: Could you please explain in detail?

Comment: Have you tried anything or did you just go to StackOverflow to find someone to do it for you?

Comment: I am new here.  apologies if i didnt follow protocol.

Comment: This is what i tried

Comment: For next time, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Will do so. Thanks for the direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join and aggregation:

```
select f1.user, f2.user, count(*)
from friends f1 join
     friends f2
     on f1.friend = f2.friend and
        f1.user < f2.user
group by f1.user, f2.user;
```